# emacs doesn't respond right off the bat

Tags: emacs

I just installed `emacs` and when I start it, it appears but it doesn't react to keypresses. It consumes most of the CPU. I have no `~/.emacs` and run it this way:

```
emacs -Q --debug-init
```

Also `strace -p $(pgrep emacs)` doesn't produce any output and I don't understand what's going on. I'm running `debian 6 (squeeze)` under `virtualbox` but I doubt it's related. It works fine on other `VMs`. Any help is appreciated.

**UPD** I realised that for a while this system had `stable` in its `sources.list` and I've installed some `wheezy` packages, so it may be the cause.

Comment: Does it work with "emacs -nw"?  Do you see anything suspicious if you do "strace emacs -Q"? "ltrace emacs -Q"?

Comment: It might be important what Emacs version you have. If it is a recent development snapshot, for instance, then you can expect bugs. I have seen problems with memory leaks, for instance. If you are using a dev snapshot, do you also have a standard Emacs release that you can use, to test and compare with?

Comment: Running `emacs -nw` doesn't help, btw I'm running it in `putty`. And `strace emacs -Q` does produces [strange output](http://sprunge.us/ABTd). And it goes on and on.